# DirectoryNotFoundException for nuget package staticwebassets

Tags: asp.net, docker-compose, plotly, blazor-server-side

I've been having an issue regarding the loading of staticwebassets for a nuget package during the building of my docker image. I am getting the following error:

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: /root/.nuget/packages/plotly.blazor/4.1.0/staticwebassets/

I am using .NET 6.0 and Blazor server side.

## My Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:buster-slim AS debian
RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /srcCOPY ["EventTimeline.csproj",     "EventTimeline.csproj"]
COPY ["wwwroot", "/src/wwwroot"]
RUN dotnet restore "EventTimeline.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR /srcRUN dotnet build "EventTimeline.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

COPY --from=debian /usr/share/doc/perl-base /bin/release

COPY --from=build /app/build .

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "EventTimeline.csproj" -c 
Release -o /app/publishWORKDIR /workdir    

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "EventTimeline.dll"]
```

## My Program.cs:

```
using EventTimeline.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using MudBlazor.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to thecontainer.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<EventTimeline.Helpers.IDataContext, EventTimeline.Helpers.DataContext>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

builder.Services.AddMudServices();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IClientService, ClientService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISleepService, SleepService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMedicineService, MedicineService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();`
```

During my search for the answer I found a [solution](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19292), however, I already implemented these uses.

Before this I was already having issues with nuget packages not updating and first the dockerfile not loading wwwroot (I fixed it). I am sure it is not the package itself, since I also had this error with a package that I was not using (so I deleted it). I have also tried reinstalling the package.

Many thanks!

EDIT: formatting

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the solution I found is good coding practice, however, this is for a school project that is due soon so I decided it was the best option.

I added the

> /root/.nuget/packages/plotly.blazor/4.1.0/staticwebassets/

To my docker-compose file.

```
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: Dockerfile
  depends_on:
   - db
  ports:
   - "8888:80"
  volumes:
  - /wwwroot:/src/wwwroot
  - /root/.nuget/packages/plotly.blazor/2.18.2/staticwebassets/:/root/.nuget/packages/plotly.blazor/2.18.2/staticwebassets/


Let me know if you know a better solution!
```